# Why is my django session not persisting? It works when I use Postman but not when I try through my Frontend

Tags: python, django, mongodb, session, pymongo

I'm currently working on a registration component for an application built using React with TypeScript and Tailwind CSS, Django and MongoDB.

In my Django backend I have an app called `login_register_app`, which is used for registration functionality. I want to create a session that stores the id of the document when the document is created so that when the user is asked to add further details on the following page the correct document can be updated. So far, I have the following function for registration:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def create_login(request):
    # parse json
    body = json.loads(request.body)

    # get email and password and confirm password
    email = body.get('email')
    password = body.get('password')
    confirm_password = body.get('confirm_password')

    email_is_valid = False
    password_is_valid = False
    error = ''

    # password must be at least 8 characters and contain digit 0 - 9, Uppercase, Lowercase and Special
    # character from list (#?!@$%^&*-)
    password_validation_pattern = re.compile('^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}$')

    # compare password to confirm password and regex pattern
    if password == confirm_password and re.match(password_validation_pattern, password):
        password_is_valid = True
    elif password == confirm_password:
        error = 'password is not valid. Requires at least one uppercase, lowercase, digit and special character [#?!@$%^&*-]'
    else:
        error = 'passwords do not match'
        
    # verify email does not already exist in the database
    if not users_collection.find_one({'email': email}):
        email_is_valid = True
    else:
        error = 'email already exists'


    # hash password before storing in database
    hashed_password = make_password(password)

    # save to database
    if email_is_valid and password_is_valid:
        document = users_collection.insert_one({
            'email': email,
            'password': hashed_password,
        })

        # create session to track the user id
        user_id = document.inserted_id
        request.session['user_id'] = str(user_id)
        print(request.session.items())
    

    return JsonResponse(
        {
            'emailIsValid': email_is_valid,
            'passwordIsValid': password_is_valid,
            'errorMessage': error
        }
    )
```

As you can see, a session is created following the successful creation of a new document in the MongoDB database to store a session called `user_id`.

In the same `views.py` file, I have a second function responsible for dealing with the additional information the user inputs such as name, date of birth, etc. In order to correctly update the relevant document, I attempt to access the session I previously created using `document = users_collection.find_one({"_id": bson.ObjectId(request.session['user_id'])})` as seen in the code below:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def add_core_user_details(request):
    # parse json
    body = json.loads(request.body)

    # get all values
    first_name = body.get('first_name')
    last_name = body.get('last_name')
    date_of_birth = body.get('date_of_birth')
    gender = body.get('gender')
    phone_number = body.get('phone_number')
    athlete_or_coach = body.get('athlete_or_coach')

    problem = ''
    error_message = ''

    # verify first and surname only have alphabetic values
    if len(first_name) in [0, 1]:
        problem = 'First Name'
        error_message = 'First name is required and must contain more than 1 character'
    elif not first_name.isalpha():
        problem = 'First Name'
        error_message = 'First name must only contain alphabetic characters'
    
    if len(last_name) in [0, 1]:
        problem = 'Last Name'
        error_message = 'Last name is required and must contain more than 1 character'
    elif not last_name.isalpha():
        problem = 'Last Name'
        error_message = 'Last name must only contain alphabetic characters'

    # convert date_of_birth to type datetime
    if date_of_birth is None:
        problem = 'Date of Birth'
        error_message = 'Date of birth is required'
    else:
        date_regex_pattern = re.compile(r'^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])/[0-9]{4}$')
        date_format = '%d/%m/%Y'

        if re.match(date_regex_pattern, date_of_birth):
            date_of_birth = datetime.strptime(date_of_birth, date_format)
        else:
            problem = 'Date of Birth'
            error_message = 'Date in invalid format, must be DD/MM/YYYY'

    # check gender is either male or female
    if gender not in ['Male', 'Female']:
        problem = 'Gender'
        error_message = 'Must be either male or female'

    # parse phone number to remove any non-numeric values
    phone_number = re.sub(r'[^0-9]', '', phone_number)

    if len(phone_number) not in [9, 10] or phone_number[0] != '0':
        problem = 'Phone Number'
        error_message = 'Invalid phone number'
    

    # check athlete or coach is either athlete, coach or both
    if athlete_or_coach not in ['Athlete', 'Coach', 'Both']:
        problem = 'Athlete or Coach'
        error_message = 'Must be either athlete, coach or both'
    
    print(request.session.items())
    
    
    if error_message == '' and problem == '':
        # save to database
        document = users_collection.find_one({"_id": bson.ObjectId(request.session['user_id'])})
        
        update = {'$set':{
            'first_name': first_name,
            'last_name': last_name,
            'date_of_birth': date_of_birth,
            'gender': gender,
            'phone_number': phone_number,
            'user_type': athlete_or_coach
        }}

        users_collection.update_one({"_id": bson.ObjectId(request.session['user_id'])}, update)

    return JsonResponse({
        'problem': problem,
        'errorMessage': error_message
    })
```

However, when I do this I get a KeyError suggesting that the key `user_id` does not exist within the session dictionary but when I check the session dictionary after initially creating the session I can see that its there as shown in the stack trace below where the session dictionary for the first API call (`login-register/create-login/`) in on line 1 of the stack trace and the session dictionary for the second API call (`login-register/core-details/`) can be seen on line 3 of the stack trace:

```
dict_items([('user_id', '63e0f975611b8440139c674c')])
[06/Feb/2023 12:58:29] "POST /login-register/create-login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 67
dict_items([])
Internal Server Error: /login-register/core-details/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bench\Documents\GitHub\z12-performance-webapp\server\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bench\Documents\GitHub\z12-performance-webapp\server\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bench\Documents\GitHub\z12-performance-webapp\server\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bench\Documents\GitHub\z12-performance-webapp\server\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 103, in view  
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bench\Documents\GitHub\z12-performance-webapp\server\.venv\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch   
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bench\Documents\GitHub\z12-performance-webapp\server\.venv\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\bench\Documents\GitHub\z12-performance-webapp\server\.venv\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\bench\Documents\GitHub\z12-performance-webapp\server\.venv\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch   
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bench\Documents\GitHub\z12-performance-webapp\server\.venv\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\decorators.py", line 50, in handler    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bench\Documents\GitHub\z12-performance-webapp\server\login_register_app\views.py", line 175, in add_core_user_details
    document = users_collection.find_one({"_id": bson.ObjectId(request.session['user_id'])})
                                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bench\Documents\GitHub\z12-performance-webapp\server\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\base.py", line 53, in __getitem__
    return self._session[key]
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^
KeyError: 'user_id'
```

What I find to be most confusing is that when I test this functionality using Postman, it works as intended i.e. the session is stored by the first API call and is available for the second API call allowing the document to be updated correctly in the MongoDB database. But when I use my React frontend it does not work the same as shown by the stack trace above. This lead me to initially believe this to be a frontend issue however, after testing I am certain that the data is being passed correctly from the frontend to the backend.

Additionally, when I check the database via the /admin page of the django project I don't see a table for sessions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why not use Djangos built in authentication module?  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/

Comment: @Orion447 have you used this? My understanding was that it only worked with SQL databases but maybe I'm wrong. Would this solve the issue with the sessions?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're going about this the wrong way. Sessions should be tracked on the client side, not the server side. After successful registration/authentication, a token is sent in the API response which is stored in `localStorage` and used in following requests to identify the user. The way you're going about this now requires your Django backend to be stateful which does not follow REST architecture.

Instead, you should (ideally) use the Django authentication system to register your user and then track their progress through your form on the front-end.